# Replace negatives with zeros in a dataframe column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe containing two columns.

The first column is the date index.

Each row of the second column is a list of 60 numbers that include negative values.

```
                    Spc
1976-10-31 15:00:00 [0.0124, 0.0096, 0.0325, 0.1562, 0.4494, 0.738...-1., -1., -1., -1.]
1976-11-01 03:00:00 [0.0254, 0.0299, 0.0273, 0.1229, 0.596, 0.9833...-1., -1., -1., -1.]
1976-11-01 15:00:00 [0.0226, 0.0236, 0.0269, 0.085, 0.4163, 0.8011...-1., -1., -1., -1.]
1976-11-02 03:00:00 [0.0132, 0.0154, 0.0172, 0.1336, 0.4743, 0.694...-1., -1., -1., -1.]
1976-11-02 15:00:00 [0.0124, 0.0169, 0.028, 0.5028, 1.4503, 1.6055...-1., -1., -1., -1.]
     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :     :
2017-05-20 04:00:00 [5.374061e-13, 1.2720002e-06, 0.00052255474, 0...2.8157034e-03, 1.4578120e-03]
2017-05-20 04:30:00 [1.2021946e-12, 3.3477074e-06, 0.0014435094, 0...5.88221522e-03, 3.44922021e-03]
2017-05-20 05:00:00 [1.2236685e-13, 5.018357e-07, 0.00023753957, 0...2.28277827e-03, 1.07194704e-03]
2017-05-20 05:30:00 [3.5527579e-13, 1.1004944e-06, 0.0005480177, 0...2.0632602e-03, 1.6171171e-03]
2017-05-20 06:00:00 [4.968573e-13, 1.4969078e-06, 0.00065009575, 0...1.21051911e-03, 1.18123344e-03]
```

**I want to replace all negative values in this column with zeros.**

Here is the complete data for the first two rows:

```py
1976-10-31 15:00:00 [ 0.0013,  0.0016,  0.007,   0.03,    0.0803,  0.2318,  0.5842,  0.8401,  0.6,
  0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,
  0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,
  0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,
  0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,
  0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,     -1.,     -1.,     -1.,
 -1.,     -1.,     -1.,     -1.,     -1.,     -1.    ]
1976-11-01 03:00:00 [ 0.0022,  0.004,   0.0104,  0.0512,  0.1112,  0.2227,  0.5263,  0.7085,  0.4,
  0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,
  0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,
  0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,
  0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,
  0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,      0.,     -1.,     -1.,     -1.,
 -1.,     -1.,     -1.,     -1.,     -1.,     -1.    ]
```

Currently, my solution is to convert the column of lists into a separate df of 60 columns. I can then convert the negatives into zeros in this df.

```
# Convert the spectral ordinates from DF column of lists into columns
Spc = df_PRIM_SECO.Spc.apply(pd.Series)

# Set all negative values in DF to zero
Spc[Spc < 0] = 0
```

Although this does the job, the .apply() operation is slow (taking 1.3 minutes for a df with 400,000 rows).

Could someone please offer a more efficient (faster) alternative?

Comment: Could you please post more clear samples(means without dots etc) so that we could test our codes too.

Comment: In pandas, you should not be storing nested objects like lists within columns. Keep primitive, atomic types (i.e., `bool`, `int`, `float`, `str`) in columns for proper analyses (i.e., aggregation, modeling, plotting).

Comment: Each row is similar to this:<br/>0.0012, 0.0012, 0.0243, 0.0904, 0.1526, 0.196, 0.202, 0.1468, 0.1006, 0.0855, 0.0759, 0.0547, 0.0278, 0.0162, 0.0121, 0.0096, 0.0096, 0.0096, 0.0103, 0.0154, 0.0209, 0.0228, 0.0214, 0.0165, 0.0117, 0.0089, 0.0072, 0.0059, 0.0042, 0.0033, 0.0028, 0.0017, 0.0011, 0.0008, 0.0006, 0.0004, 0.0003, 0.0002, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 1e-04, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0

Comment: Be careful, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style! I know you already got an answer, but can you share a little more about your program and data? There may be another data structure more suited to the task.

Comment: By the way, do you want to assign the result back to the same column? I hadn't noticed the comment by @Parfait earlier, but I agree entirely.

Comment: AMC, First point noted - I've come from a programming background where case sensitivity was not an issue. Each row of my data contains 60 band-averaged spectral ordinates (at 0.01Hz spacing) resulting from a spectral analysis of ocean wave records. The negatives in this data were a crude padding of data from an earlier (pre-1990) analysis method that collected fewer ordinates. I need to remove these negatives prior to calculating spectral moments (m0, m1, m2, m4), and then the wave parameters derived from these moments (as these calculations involve square root, i.e. hm0 = 4*np.sqrt(m0)).

Comment: @JimWaldron Your DataFrame only has two columns? Also, I just posted some timings, if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few solutions, with some basic timings.

---

Setup code, and test data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

num_rows = 100000

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col_1': np.random.randint(0, 100, num_rows),
                          'col_2': np.random.uniform(-10, 10, (num_rows, 60)).tolist()})
```

---

#### 1. `.apply(pd.Series)` : ~18,400 ms

```py
def func_1(df_in):
    df_in = df_in.copy()
    temp = df_in['col_2'].apply(pd.Series)
    temp[temp < 0] = 0
    df_in['col_2'] = temp.to_numpy().tolist()
    return df_in
```

#### 2. List comprehension : ~460 ms

```py
def func_2(df_in):
    df_in = df_in.copy()
    df_in['col_2'] = df_in['col_2'].map(lambda l: [0 if elem < 0 else elem for elem in l])
    return df_in
```

#### 3. Solution by @Valdi_Bo : ~832 ms

```py
def func_3(df_in):
    df_in = df_in.copy()
    df_in['col_2'] = np.array([np.array(elem) for elem in df_in['col_2']]).clip(min=0).tolist()
    return df_in
```

#### 4. Solution similar in principle to the one by @Valdi_Bo : ~926 ms

```py
def func_4(df_in):
    df_in = df_in.copy()
    df_in['col_2'] = np.stack(df_in['col_2'].to_numpy()).clip(min=0).tolist()
    return df_in
```

#### 5. A cousin of 3 and 4 : ~691 ms

```py
def func_5(df_in):
    df_in = df_in.copy()
    df_in['col_2'] = np.array(df_in['col_2'].tolist()).clip(min=0).tolist()
    return df_in
```

---

Note: The relative speed differences are maintained on an input with 10 times the amount of rows (1,000,000 instead of 100,000).

Comment: You could even use numba and reduce the calculation time again

Comment: @NaturalFrequency For which function? All of them?

Comment: No, actually you'd have to rewrite a function to have a ``numpy array`` as input and loop over it. 

``@njit
def func_numba(arr):
    for i in arr.shape[0]:
        for j in arr.shape[1]:
            if arr[i][j] < 0 : 
                 arr[i][j] = 0``

Comment: @NaturalFrequency Do you think there would be any performance gains? Are you going to give it a try?

Comment: I did and it was faster but I think most of the time is spent of copying the data from list to array, which I left in the computation for fairness. Altough I'm not gonna re-benchmark everything it came at around half the time of solution 5 for me

Comment: @NaturalFrequency So ~400 ms? I didn't expect that, can you share the code?

Comment: Sure, note that you should run ´´test_numba`` once before because of compiling, if you find the comparison fair: here is the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/r2YSPRqN)

Comment: @JimWaldron Which method did you use? Did it work correctly?

Comment: @AMC - I have now applied your suggestions to a df containing 377,069 rows. You might be interested in the performance times for each: Platform =  win32
Original solution by Valdi_BoTest 1  1.0540163760001633
1. .apply(pd.Series) : 92.86281788899987
2. List comprehension : 88.58585064599993
3. Solution by Valdi_Bo : 4.223679129999709
4. Solution similar in principle to the one by Valdi_Bo : 3.3187198809996517
5. A cousin of 3 and 4 : 3.3977148859999033

Comment: It seems like there 2 times for solution 1, am I reading this wrong? What's the unit for these measurements, do they all share the same one?

Comment: @AMC - Times are in seconds. Valdi_Bo's code was the fastest (1.05s); next was your Solution 4 (3.32s); then your Solution 5 (3.4s); then your Solution 3 (4.22s). My original effort  (apply(pd.Series) ) took a staggering 92.86s!!!

Comment: @JimWaldron Hmm, those times are not what I would have expected!

Answer (score 1):

*Pandas* is known to operate slower than the underlying *Numpy*.

So maybe just *Numpy* is what you actually need?

Based on your data sample (20 rows with 10 numbers in the list)
I prepared 2 tests functions:

```
def f1():
    Spc = df.Spc.apply(pd.Series)
    Spc[Spc < 0] = 0

def f2():
    np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in df.Spc]).clip(min=0)
```

I checked their execution time with *%timeit* and got:

- 39.3 ms for *f1()*,
- 425 µs for *f2()*.

So the second function, based on *Numpy*, operates about **90** times quicker.

The downside is that the result is a *Numpy* array, but maybe
it is sufficient for you.

Comment: Valdi_Bo, Thank you! Your solution is absolutely amazing! Regards,JW